# AngularJS: I can repeatly call a function with some time interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, intervals, repeat

is there any way that I can repeatly call a function in angularjs. i'm using this in my controller:

```
$interval( $rootScope.synchronization(), 1000 );
```

but it calls synchronization function only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular's $interval. The fn function is executed every delay milliseconds as:

```
$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
```

for example, try this:

```
$scope.myVariable = 1;
$interval( function(){
    $scope.myVariable++;
}, 1000 );
```

So the first parameter on $interval must be a function, $rootScope.synchronization() is not a function, it is a call to a function. In your case change $rootScope.synchronization() to $rootScope.synchronization

```
$interval( $rootScope.synchronization, 1000 );
```

Comment: Your last sample has an error where you create anonymous function and you don't actually do anything inside it. It should be either `$interval($rootScope.synchronization, 1000);` or `$interval( function(){
    $rootScope.synchronization();
}, 1000 );`

Comment: your are right, that code was bad, so sorry. I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets:

```
$interval( $rootScope.synchronization, 1000 );
```

Passing the call with brackets executes the function and then the result is passed to $interval as an argument. Without brackets you actually pass the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

With the parens, you are only calling it, not passing a reference to the function.

```
$interval( $rootScope.synchronization, 1000 );
```